# Split dictionaries in list into 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, string, list, numpy

I have a list of dictionaries that I want to split up so that it becomes a 2D array. An example of a 2 dictionaries in the list is:

```
{"house_size": 93.0, "build_year": 2002.0, "house_color": 3, "price": 2498.0}
{"house_size": 75.0, "build_year": 1954.0, "house_color": 1, "price": 2953.0}
```

I want to split it by "," so that the array would have 4 columns insted of it all being 1 column.

Top half is loading json file.

```
import os
import json
import numpy
def load_line_json(path): 
    dataset = []
    with open(path, "r") as fp:
        for line in fp:
            example = json.loads(line)
            dataset.append(example)
    
    print("loaded dataset, with {} examples from: {}.".format(len(dataset), path))
    return dataset
        
path_to_dataset = "/Users/PathToFile"
path_to_test = os.path.join(path_to_dataset, "test.json")

assert os.path.isfile(path_to_test)
 
test_dataset = load_line_json(path_to_test)
dat = []
for string in test_dataset:
    dat.append([string for string in string])
print(dat[0])
print("-----------------------\n")
print(test_dataset[0])
print(type(test_dataset))

data = np.array(dat)
data1 = np.array(test_dataset)

print(data)

print("Shape is: ", data.shape)
print("Shape is: ", data1.shape)
```

I have attemted to split it up like shown below but it removes the values after `:` so it becomes just "'house_size'" and not "'house_size': 93.0" like I want. I make it to an array and the shape sould be (rows, 4) not (rows,) as it is before I split. Basically I want to split it up by the comma sign.

```
dat = []
for string in test_dataset:
    dat.append([string for string in string])
```

Comment: `dataset` is a list of dictionaries, not a list of strings.

Comment: ok thanks I just asumed is was strings, I will edit my question

Comment: Use `string.entries()` to get a sequence of keys and values.

Comment: BTW, it's really confusing to reuse the same `string` variable like that.

Comment: `dat = [list(d.values()) for d in test_dataset]`?

Comment: It worked with ```dat = [list(d.values()) for d in test_dataset]```, my itentions was to keep "house_size: 93.0" but it works with just the values aswell. But I don't really need more than just the values so your solution worked perfect as it was just the shape I was interesting in. Thank you so much!

Comment: @eloen - any feedback on my answer is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, this is what you are looking for

```
dic = {"house_size": 93.0, "build_year": 2002.0, "house_color": 3, "price": 2498.0}
list(dic.items())
```

This will yield:

```
[('house_size', 93.0), ('build_year', 2002.0), ('house_color', 3), ('price', 2498.0)]
```